# Detect single controlevent for all buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I know I can detect if my button is being held down by adding a selector like this

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

But with 50+ buttons in a single view I have I'm trying to see if theres a way to add a selector to ALL buttons in my view and see if theres a button being held down and which button is it.

Im wondering because I need to detect UIControlEventTouchDown AND UIControlEventTouchUpInside on 50+ buttons so thats a lot of code id like to shorten down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With arrays.

```
for (UIButton *button in self.arrayOfButtons) {
    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonDown:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonUp:)  // it's cold outside
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

---

Your `buttonDown:` and `buttonUp:` methods should look like this:

```
- (void)buttonDown:(id)sender
```

OR

```
- (void)buttonDown:(UIButton *)button
```

Either way, `sender` or `button` is going to be a reference to the object that has called the method.

If you have `btnFoo` and `btnBar` and you give both of them `buttonDown:` for the touch down event, then `sender` or `button` will tell you WHICH button was pressed to get into the method.

To more completely see what's going on, give all your buttons a tag, and throw this line of code in the method:

```
NSLog(@"Button.tag = %d", button.tag);
```

Comment: if i use button as the parameter to detect which button is being held down will this work? for ex. @selector(buttonUp:button)